# Can the gate length of transistor be varied to arbitrary but reasonable values in any technology node?

Tags: mosfet, finfet

Let's take two technology nodes 14 nm and 65 nm. 14 nm node uses FinFET transistors whereas 65 nm uses planar CMOS (as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong).
Can the gate length of the transistors be varied to arbitrary values like 100 nm or 200 nm in both of these technology nodes?
MOSFET gate length can be varied as per requirement but can the gate length of FinFET be changed to any value too? Does gate length have a certain allowed range, like a maximum value, for FinFETs of, say, 14 nm node?

Comment: any answers anyone :(